# Change of Variables Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, linear-transformations

Suppose $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Gaussian random vector such that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_X)$. I am trying to figure out if it's possible to calculate the PDF for the vector $Y := KX$, where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, so that $K\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. For the case where $K$ is a square matrix, I know how to get the PDF, but when it is not square, I cannot take the inverse so the usual change of variables procedure doesn't work. Is it possible to construct the pdf of $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to be familiar with the characteristic function of multivariate random variables. For example, $X$ has characteristic function $\Bbb E\exp(it^TX)=\exp(-\tfrac12t^T\Sigma_Xt)$, so the characteristic function of $Y$ is$$\Bbb E\exp it^TY=\Bbb\exp i(K^Tt)^TX=\exp(-\tfrac12t^TK\Sigma_XK^Tt).$$Hence $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,K\Sigma_XK^T)$.